# Adding Workspace to Azure ML

Tags: azure, machine-learning, jupyter, workspace

I am learning ML using Azure. I am trying to feed the output of my experiment from Azure Machine Learning Studio to Paython3. I have converted the output of my Azure ML experiment to CSV and while trying to open the output in a Paython 3 Jupyter notebook, I get the following error

```puthon
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-879de613d8dc> in <module>()
      1 from azureml import Workspace
----> 2 ws = Workspace()
      3 experiment = ws.experiments['04cff8814e1949fd957b40192cc7eac7.f-id.3be55208572740e08a9a4c7937398866']
      4 ds = experiment.get_intermediate_dataset(
      5     node_id='4dc79617-ac81-45ba-a807-4e646ae1de29-403',

/home/nbuser/anaconda3_23/lib/python3.4/site-packages/azureml/__init__.py in __init__(self, workspace_id, authorization_token, endpoint)
    883         endpoint = https://studio.azureml.net
    884         """
--> 885         workspace_id, authorization_token, endpoint, management_endpoint = _get_workspace_info(workspace_id, authorization_token, endpoint, None)
    886 
    887         _not_none_or_empty('workspace_id', workspace_id)

/home/nbuser/anaconda3_23/lib/python3.4/site-packages/azureml/__init__.py in _get_workspace_info(workspace_id, authorization_token, endpoint, management_endpoint)
    849 
    850         if workspace_id is None:
--> 851             raise ValueError('workspace_id not provided and not available via config')
    852         if authorization_token is None:
    853             raise ValueError('authorization_token not provided and not available via config')

ValueError: workspace_id not provided and not available via config
```

[Image of Error Returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5doQJ.png) 
Appreciate if someone can help me with this error?

Answer (score 0):

In your codes:
----> 2 ws = Workspace()

You should use:
ws = Workspace('workspace_id', 'authorization_token')

The accept input parameters are: workspace_id, authorization_token, endpoint, management_endpoint, Which workspace_id, authorization_token are required I think.

You can find the information under'Settings' from Azure ML studio web portal. Hope this will help. (And remember don't post your keys online :P )